# Image optimization affecting EXIF data and hence affecting SEO

Tags: html, seo

I've heard that image optimization softwares remove EXIF Data, an act that may affect SEO since EXIF Data as far as I know, is somehow related to SEO rankings. Is this true?

([source](http://www.pitstopmedia.com/sem/img-tag-image-seo))

Comment: Please read the description of the `seo` tag you have put on your question.

Comment: oh i see . . . thanks for notifying me bout that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question can be separated into two issues which follow.

### **Do the search engines use EXIF**

The main issue is if search engines actually use the EXIF data. There is the view that some sites read the EXIF data and ustilize this data in the DB, etc. It has also been shown that google image search malkes use of EXIF data:

- http://blog.pizzaseo.com/exif-tags-impact-on-google/
- http://www.petapixel.com/2011/07/25/google-adds-exif-data-to-image-search/

There is however the view also that EXIF (except for google image search) does not add much else:

- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8174/any-seo-sense-in-embedding-exif-metadata-on-web-site-images

*So I would say that it is something to **keep an eye** on if it changes or is used anywhere else.*

### **Do Image Editors/Optimizers rip out EXIF data**

Most photographs produced by digitial video cameras do not include all that much highly relevant exif information.

If an application such as google picasa (or another) has been used to add information (such as a comment/description, gps coordinates, etc), using an image editor and resaving/exporting the image can lead to the EXIF data not being written.

It all comes down to if the image optimizer/editor supports EXIF tags and if it will save them.

BTW: EXIF is not supported in JPEG 2000, PNG, or GIF.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format for information related to the spec.

Comment: i'm wondering . . . are EXIF Datas really a big deal after all ? Based on research I think my current optimization software "smush.it" is removing EXIF Data.

Comment: From what I've been reading google image search makes use of it, but overall it is not a huge deal...yet. I think though if you have the EXIF data, I'd try to not "smush it". However, it would be important to be more meaningful EXIF data such as GPS coordinates or Description.